# Splitting a tuple in to a list without splitting it in to individual characters

Tags: python, string, list, tuples

I am having issues with my Python code. I want to get the values from a tuple and put them in to lists. In the example below, I would like to get the artists in to one list, and the earnings in to another. Then put those in to a tuple.

```
def sort_artists(x):
    artist = []
    earnings = []
    z = (artist, earnings)
    for inner in x:
        artist += inner[0]
        earnings += inner[1]
    return z

artists = [("The Beatles", 270.8), ("Elvis Presley", 211.5), ("Michael Jackson", 183.9)]
print(sort_artists(artists))
```

I can print `inner[0] and that will give me 'The Beatles', but when I try to append it to the empty list, it splits it up in to individual letters. What is wrong?

The error (though I have tried it without the 'earnings' bit too, as well as using `append`, and other things:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Artists.py", line 43, in <module>
    print(sort_artists(artists))
  File "Artists.py", line 31, in sort_artists
    earnings += inner[1]
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
Command exited with non-zero status 1
```

The desired output:

```
(['Elvis Presley', 'Michael Jackson', 'The Beatles'], [270.8, 211.5, 183.9])
```

This is what is currently happening (without the earnings bit):

```
(['T', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'B', 'e', 'a', 't', 'l', 'e', 's', 'E', 'l', 'v', 'i', 's', ' ', 'P', 'r', 'e', 's', 'l', 'e', 'y', 'M', 'i', 'c', 'h', 'a', 'e', 'l', ' ', 'J', 'a', 'c', 'k', 's', 'o', 'n'], [])
```

Comment: _"What is wrong?"_  In your context, `+` is **concatenation** of sequences, so `[]` is a sequence and `"The Beatles"` is a string that is a sequence of characters, so you have the equivalent of `[]+['a','b']` (try it in the interpreter).  You MUST use the `.append(object)` method of lists, that doesn't _unpack_ its argument and just inserts it at the end of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code :

```
def sort_artists(x):
    artist = []
    earnings = []
    z = (artist, earnings)
    for inner in x:
        artist.append(inner[0])
        earnings.append(inner[1])
    return z

artists = [("The Beatles", 270.8), ("Elvis Presley", 211.5), ("Michael Jackson", 183.9)]
print(sort_artists(artists))
```

output:

```
(['The Beatles', 'Elvis Presley', 'Michael Jackson'], [270.8, 211.5, 183.9])
```

Comment: Thanks. Was the `+=` the wrong thing to use? Is that only for single characters?

Comment: @william3031 using `+=` tries to concatenate lists. e.g. `[1,2] + [3,4] == [1,2,3,4]`... the problem you had is that a string can be considered a list of characters, that's why you got them individually

Answer (score 3):

you can use the built-in function `zip` to split the lists in one short expression:

```py
def sort_artists(x):
    return tuple(list(t) for t in zip(*x))

artists = [("The Beatles", 270.8), ("Elvis Presley", 211.5), ("Michael Jackson", 183.9)]
print(sort_artists(artists))
```

Output:

```
(['The Beatles', 'Elvis Presley', 'Michael Jackson'], [270.8, 211.5, 183.9])
```

Comment: It's a tuple of tuples, OP asks for a tuple of lists (probably they don't even care, but I'm here to be nitpicking :-) +1

Comment: @gboffi If you reached here 2 years later, it's worth fixing :P

Answer (score 1):

```
def sort_artists(x):
    artist = []
    earnings = [] 
    for i in range(len(x)):
        artist.append(x[i][0])
        earnings.append(x[i][1])
    return (artist,earnings)
```

we can access element of list by it position

```
print(artist[0]) 
#o/p
('The Beatles', 270.8)
```

now we can unpack the tuple using index as well

```
#for artist
print(artist[0][0])
o/p
'The Beatles'

#for earnings
print(artist[0][1])
o/p
270.8
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def sort_artists(x):
    artist = []
    earnings = []
    z = (artist, earnings)
    for inner in x:
        artist.append(inner[0])
        earnings.append(inner[1])
    artist.sort()
    earnings.sort()
    earnings.reverse()
    return z
```